# Node.js : How do I get an Alexa sessionId and userID?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill, and it requires saving userID and sessionID to the Database. For database, I am using MongoDb. So far, I have used **handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.sessionID** to obtain the sessionID, and to get the userID, I am applying ***handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userID***. However, I am receiving undefined values for both session and user ID. Here is the Code:

```
    const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Hi, I am Nao. I am here to give you counseling on your anxiety issues. Can I have your name, please? Note: We are not professional therapists or counselors. ';
      
       //These two lines of code is for testing purpose//
      const useri=handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userID;
      const g=handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.sessionID;
      
      

        const curr_session=new post.session({
            alexa_sessionid:handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.sessionID
        });
        
        let user=await post.findOne({userID:handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userID});
         if(!user){
              user=new post({
            userID:handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userID
        });
             
         }
        user.session_list.push(curr_session);
        user.save();
         
         
      
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput+g)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

How can I get the Alexa session and UserId by using handlerInput?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be easy to spot if you compare your code to an actual JSON request for your skill, but the error is your capital case spelling of "ID" in the name of the elements ("userID", "sessionID").
The request uses a camel case: "userId" and "sessionId".

If you replace the occurrences in your code accordingly you should get the values.